# How to get a single line title in a Manipulate box?

Tags: manipulate, output-formatting, text-formatting, textalignment

I'm having a text output issue with the following code:

```
Manipulate[
1,
{{n, 1, Style["n :", 12]}, 0, 15, 1},
{{m, 0, Style["m :", 12]}, 0, 15, 1},
ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
FrameMargins -> None,
FrameLabel -> {
None, None,
Style["A long line of text as title "

            "the rest of the long title",
Bold, 18, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]
    }
]
```

The title text should be displayed as a single line title in the Manipulate box with the proper order.  Currently, the order doesn't match (it is reversed!).  I'm sure this should be very simple to do, but I'm yet unable to get it right.

So if my code has the title broken on two lines like the above example, but need to be displayed in a single line with the proper order, how should I do it?

Comment: It looks like you're multiplying two strings, and `Times[]` sorts its arguments. Maybe you could use `Row`?

Comment: The order doesn't reverse for me, but also you don't need to use two strings to split it up...? That can just be one string

Comment: @b3m2a1, for reasons that I can't explain here (it would be too long and not very interesting), I have to split the title in two strings, on two lines in the code.  I very rarely have to do this.  In brief, it's because the code is a copy/paste part from a PDF document I'm writing.

Comment: @MichaelE2, the **Row** command appears to solve nicely my issue.  Thanks!

Comment: You could also concatenate the strings with `<>`

Comment: @MelaGo, I don't know this option.  Can you offer an example as an answer?  If it works, I'll mark your answer.

Comment: For example, `Style["A long line of text as title "<>"the rest of the long title", Bold, 18, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]`

Comment: Or use `StringForm` to combine any two expressions whether they are strings or not

Comment: The <> suggestion from @MelaGo is exactly what I was looking for.